# Propel filtering a CrossRef Table

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I'm new to Propel and i stumble by filtering by a Cross Reference Table.

I have 4 Tables:

1. Company
2. Vertical Chain
3. "Vertical Chain to Company"
4. "Vertical Chain Sub Element"

The third Table (Vertical Chain to Company) is a cross reference table between Company and the Vertical Chain Sub Element.
The fourth table (Vertical Chain Sub Element) has a foreign key to the Vertical Chain Table.

I tried to visualize it:
[image]

My schema.xml looks simplified like this:

**Company Table**

```
<table name="company">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="255" required="true"/>

    [...]

 </table>
```

**Vertical Chain To Company**

```
<table name="verticalcain_company" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="company_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="verticalchainsubelement_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="company" phpName="CompanyElement">
        <reference local="company_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="verticalchainsubelement" phpName="SubVerticalChainElement">
        <reference local="verticalchainsubelement_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

**Vertical Chain**

```
<table name="verticalchain">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="128"/>
    <column name="sequence" type="integer"/>
</table>
```

**Vertical Chain Sub Element**

```
<table name="verticalchainsubelement">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="128"/>
    <column name="verticalChain_id" type="integer"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="verticalchain" phpName="PartoOf">
        <reference local="verticalChain_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

As i wrote at the beginning i have a problem by generate the right filter.
I want to filter all companies by there vertical chain.

For example i want all companies that have "Holding" set in there financial vertical Chain but i don't know how i get this filter done.

I try to use a filter for VerticalchainCompany like this:

```
$vc_sub = VerticalchainsubelementQuery::create()->findByName("Holding");
$vc = VerticalcainCompanyQuery::create()->filterBySubVerticalChainElement($vc_sub)->find();
$comp = CompanyQuery::create()->filterByVerticalcainCompany($vc)->find();
```

But i get no Result.
So i don't know how i could realize this.

Has someone a tip oder a solution for me?

Thanks in advance!